# Doctrine PrePersist/PreUpdate don't fire

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

New-ish to Symfony (version 5), first exposure to Doctrine. I have looked through various other posts and documentations on this to no avail.

I have a simple entity with CRUD forms all working. I'd like to timestamp the entities anytime they are saved ('last updated') and figured a way to do this was using the events provided by Doctrine.

Here is the Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Utility\Role;
use App\Utility\SystemTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"username", "email"},
 *     errorPath="username",
 *     message="This username or email address is already registered."
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface {

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  private $created;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  private $changed;


  code.....


  public function getCreated(): int
  {
    return $this->created;
  }

  public function setCreated(int $created): self
  {
    $this->created = $created;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getChanged(): int
  {
    return $this->changed;
  }

  public function setChanged(int $changed): self
  {
    $this->changed = $changed;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @ORM\PrePersist
   * @ORM\PreUpdate
   */
  public function setModifiedTime() : void {
    $time = SystemTime::currentTime();

    if (is_null($this->created)) {
      $this->created = $time;
    }

    $this->changed = $time;
  }
}
```

The create and edit methods are boilerplate Maker CRUD:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="user_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'button_label' => "Create User",
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, User $user): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
      return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

According to this [documentation page on Lifecycle Callback Events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks), this should be all I need, unless I am not connecting the dots on something. Various articles say to either set these values in the constructor, or set them in the create/edit method of the controller. Neither seem correct, when it seems that this scenario is what Lifecycle Callback Events were made for.

I see there is a Doctrine bundle containing behaviors that sound like it would 'solve' this, but really wanted to learn how to do it myself first.

**edit**: Looks like PrePersist works, but PreUpdate never does (changed value never changes). Changing the user password (plainPassword) has no effect, but changing the username or role does fire the method. Why does updating the password not fire the event?

Comment: Did you clear the cache after making the changes ?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I think I understand what may be happening. plainPassword is not a Doctrine managed field or stored in the database and I assume Doctrine says the entity is unchanged, even though I also have an Event that encrypts plainPassword to the password field (which is Doctrine managed). Do I need to do something extra in the password subscriber to get preUpdate to fire?

Comment: This might be what I am actually encountering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905537/persist-entity-on-non-persisted-field-change

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. I was not looking for the right thing. It sounds like I should implement an ObjectManager for this entity, so regardless of what is changing, managed field or not, I can call my own methods before it is flushed. This seems to be what FOSUserBundle is doing.